# How to toggle an element with a specific class while having other classes

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I am trying to create a toggle component with the classes ".toggle" and ".toggle-content."

I wanted to be able to call the toggle class and show/hide the toggle-content class after it. I didn't want the element with the toggle-content class to be RIGHT after the element with the toggle class, so I created the getNextSibling() for it start at .toggle and then go to the next sibling and see if it has the toggle-content class.

So the code I provided below, it works on the elements ONLY if it has one class, which is either the .toggle or .toggle-class. If I include a class called ".red," the toggle will not work. I'm not really sure how to approach this since I'm still learning Javascript.

I'm trying to keep this pure Javascript (no jQuery or other libraries).
Any help will be appreciated!

HTML:

```
//Regular toggle
<div class="container">
  <div class="toggle">Toggle This Dropdown</div>
  <div class="toggle-content" style="display:none">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">How To Do This</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Installing in The Mid 90s</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

//If toggle class is applied to <h2> and next sibling is 
//NOT toggle-content
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="toggle">Click This Dropdown 2</h2>
  <p>Some random text between the toggle and toggle-content</p>
  <ul class="toggle-content" style="display:none">
      <li><a href="#">Boop</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bop</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

//If the toggle class is applied to <p> and has a red class
<div class="container">
  <p class="toggle red">Click This Dropdown 3</p>
  <ul class="toggle-content" style="display:none">
      <li><a href="#">Heyo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hiya</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript to detect if the next sibling is the toggle-content class

```
    var getNextSibling = function (elem, selector) {

    // Get the next sibling element
    var sibling = elem.nextElementSibling;

    // If there's no selector, return the first sibling
    if (!selector) return sibling;

    // If the sibling matches our selector, use it
    // If not, jump to the next sibling and continue the loop
    while (sibling) {
        if (sibling.matches(selector)) return sibling;
        sibling = sibling.nextElementSibling;
    }
};

function toggleDocs(event) {

    if (event.target && event.target.className == 'toggle') {

        var toggleContent = getNextSibling(event.target, '.toggle-content');

        if (toggleContent.style.display == "none") {
        toggleContent.style.display = "block";

        } else {
            toggleContent.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

document.addEventListener('click', toggleDocs, true);
```

CSS

```
.toggle {
   cursor:pointer;
}
.toggle:hover {
    color:#515151;
}

.red { color: red; }
```

Comment: this all seems a little convoluted.  What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the event.target.className == to 
event.target.className.indexOf("toggle")

Hope this helps.

```js
    var getNextSibling = function (elem, selector) {

    // Get the next sibling element
    var sibling = elem.nextElementSibling;

    // If there's no selector, return the first sibling
    if (!selector) return sibling;

    // If the sibling matches our selector, use it
    // If not, jump to the next sibling and continue the loop
    while (sibling) {
        if (sibling.matches(selector)) return sibling;
        sibling = sibling.nextElementSibling;
    }
};

function toggleDocs(event) {
    if (event.target && event.target.className.indexOf('toggle') >= 0) {

        var toggleContent = getNextSibling(event.target, '.toggle-content');

        if (toggleContent.style.display == "none") {
        toggleContent.style.display = "block";

        } else {
            toggleContent.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

document.addEventListener('click', toggleDocs, true);
```

```css
.toggle {
   cursor:pointer;
}
.toggle:hover {
    color:#515151;
}

.red { color: red; }
```

```html
//Regular toggle
<div class="container">
  <div class="toggle">Toggle This Dropdown</div>
  <div class="toggle-content" style="display:none">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">How To Do This</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Installing in The Mid 90s</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

//If toggle class is applied to <h2> and next sibling is 
//NOT toggle-content
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="toggle">Click This Dropdown 2</h2>
  <p>Some random text between the toggle and toggle-content</p>
  <ul class="toggle-content" style="display:none">
      <li><a href="#">Boop</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bop</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

//If the toggle class is applied to <p> and has a red class
<div class="container">
  <p class="toggle red">Click This Dropdown 3</p>
  <ul class="toggle-content" style="display:none">
      <li><a href="#">Heyo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hiya</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this solved my problem! I was wondering what the reason for  event.target.className.indexOf("toggle") was?

Comment: Since className returned "toggle red" for a value, I couldn't use ==, so I went for indexOf which looks to see if "toggle" is contained in className or not, so it doesn't matter if the element has "red".